# Examples of Asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithm

Here I will be giving two functions f(n) and g(n) and my aim is to decide if the f(n) is in theta, omega, big o, little o or little omega.
Please provide detailed proof if you are confident with such problems.

Problem 1: f(n) = (1/2)n^2 - 3n, g(n) = n^2

Problem 2: f(n) = 6n^3, g(n) = n^2

Problem 3: f(n) = 3n+5, g(n) = n^2

Problem 4: f(n)= n ceiling(lg n^2), g(n)= n^2 log n

Problem 5: f(n) = [10^(n+4)(n)]+6, g(n)=10^(n+3)

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow.  Help with a detail of computer implementation would be.

Comment: Actually these are some of the examples stated in Cormen chapter 3, which I had trouble understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Polynomial functions are easy.  Just compare the highest order of each.

1. f(n) is n^2 and g(n) is n^2, thus f(n) is theta g(n)
2. f(n) is n^3 and g(n) is n^2, thus f(n) is O(g(n))
3. f(n) is n and g(n) is n^2, thus f(n) is W(g(n))

A proof would involve computing the limits.

Comment: Some more functions try if you have time:

Comment: 1. f(n) = n(logn^2), g(n)= n^2logn 2. f(n)=1/sq root(n) g(n) = 1/logn